# remove text between parenthesis and change the position of words inside a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```py
pandas_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'movie': ['Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie, The (Charme discret de la bourgeoisie, Le)',
                                           'Attack Force Z (a.k.a. The Z Men) (Z-tzu te kung tui)',
                                           'State of Things, The (Stand der Dinge, Der)',
                                           'Happy Tour, A',
                                           'Awfully Big Adventure, An',
                                           'American President, The'],
                                 'genre': ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Children', 'Action', 'Documentary']})
pandas_dataframe
```

I want to apply two transformations:

- Remove any text inside parenthesis '(xxx)'
- Move the word "The" or "A" in front of the text when it is applicable (i.e. only in first and third movie title)

My final dataframe should look like this:

```py
+---------------------------------------+------------+
| movie                                 | genre      |
+---------------------------------------+------------+
| The Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie | Action     |
| Attack Force Z                        | Comedy     |
| The State of Things                   | Drama      |
| A Happy Tour                          | Children   |
| An Awfully Big Adventure              | Action     |
| The American President                | Documentary|
+---------------------------------------+------------+
```

I know that for the first transformation a regex expression should be applied. Although when I try the following,

```py
exp = r'\([^]*\)'
pandas_dataframe['movie'] = pandas_dataframe['movie'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(exp,"",x).strip())
```

I get this error: `error: unterminated character set at position 2`

In my latest edit, I added some more occasions of movies with An, A words to change position. I apologize for not including them in first place.

Answer (score 3):

Original requirements:

- move "The" to the start of the sentence
- remove text in parentheses

This moves "The" to its correct position and removes stuff within parentheses in a single expression:

```
df['movie'].str.replace(r'(.*?),?\s*(The)?\s*\(.*\)\s*', r'\2 \1')

0    The Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie
1                           Attack Force Z
2                      The State of Things
Name: movie, dtype: object
```

The Regex

```
(.*?)   # The actual movie title - first capture group
,?      # Optional comma (preceeding "The")
\s*     # Whitespace
(The)?  # Optional "The" - second capture group
\s*    
\(.*\)  # Stuff within parentheses we don't need
\s*
```

---

Updated requirements:

- move "A", "An", "The" to the start of the sentence
- remove text in parentheses *if present*

To support additional articles, let's do<sup>*</sup>

```
df['movie'].str.replace(r'(.*?),?\s*(The|A|An)?(?=\s*\(.*\)\s*|$).*', r'\2 \1')  

0    The Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie 
1                           Attack Force Z 
2                      The State of Things 
3                             A Happy Tour 
4                 An Awfully Big Adventure 
5                   The American President 
Name: movie, dtype: object
```

<sub>@Wiktor might have a shorter method to do this.</sub>

Comment: When cs95 anwers we know it's gonna be the top answer. Thanks a lot for your reply. It works as expected. Could you please modify your answer to include also the change of position of word "A" like you did with word "The". So the movie "Happy Tour, A" to become "A Happy Tour". My mistake to not include it in my PO

Comment: I have added some more options to be tackled. I am now checking my data so I apologize for not including those occasions in my initial question.

Comment: @NikSp It's a little harder but I'll see what I can do? I generally tend to discourage edits to questions midflight but in this case the additional q is small, so it's alright :-)

Comment: Thank you a lot for this and I will keep it in mind for the future. I apologize again for my edit, I am checking the data and new occasions coming up. No more edits will be done that's for sure.